How many times do we have to roll a fair 6-sided die till we roll two numbers in a row that differ by 2?
How many times do we have to roll a fair 6-sided die till we roll two numbers in a row that differ by 2?
I tried two approaches but couldn't get the answer.
First, naively I thought only an even number of rolls were possible and created a geometric distribution with $\frac{8}{36}$ probability of the rolls that differ by two. This is obviously wrong because this can happen even at 3, 5... rolls and so on.
For this, I tried to come up with a recursive solution but that didn't work out.
Any help?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Added the question to the description, hope that makes it better?

Yes, it does.${}$

I'd suggest using states, to exploit the symmetry.  There are three active states, which we can denote as ${1,2,3}$ exploiting the symmetry that $1$ and $6$ are essentially the same, as are $2,5$ and $3,4$.  Now look at the transitions between those states and use them to write a system of linear equations.

Note:  might be able to reduce this to two states by remarking that $1,2,5,6$ share the property that only one successor ends the game while $3,4$ each have two winning successors.  That might be simpler.

Should have said:  of course you can use six active states, one for each possible toss.  Nothing wrong with that, other than that it leads to a $6\times 6$ linear system.  The other two methods I described significantly get the size down.

Yes that worked

Following Lulu's second suggestion rather than having more states, let the starting state be s, and the two active states be $a =1,2,5,6,\;b = 3,4$, then
$s = \frac46(a+1) + \frac26(b+1) \tag1$
$a =\frac46(a+1) +\frac16(b+1) +\frac16\times1 \tag2$
$b = \frac26(a+1) +\frac26(b+1) +\frac26\times 1\tag 3$
Solving the set of linear equations, we get $s = \frac{17}{3}$

Your equations are correct but the answer is incorrect, it should be 17/3 with a = 5 b =4

@VaibhavDixit: Thanks, there was a typo , corrected
